# Fast food program, multiple threads and semaphores Java

Tags: java, multithreading

So I've briefly stumbled across **Semaphores** in my programming journey and ever so recently took it upon myself to devise a program replicating that of a fast food chain.

I'm going to try explain as best I can, please let me know in the comment section if I need to be more thorough

**The Plan:**

Have a ***producer*** and a ***consumer*** (tills and worker) So the tills take the order(Place them in a buffer, so a circular array..) and the worker processes that order(Takes orders out of the circular array)

I'm trying to implement semaphores so that when an order has been made, that specific till cannot be used until the worker has processed the order. And also use semaphores so that the officer can only take out one order at a time

**Here is the main method:**

```
public class FastFood {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static Buffer buff = new Buffer(2);
    static Semaphore semWorker = new Semaphore(1);
    static Semaphore semTills = new Semaphore(1);
    static int totalOrders = 10;
    static int startOrders = 0;
    static int processedOrders = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int numberOfWorkers = 2;
        int numberOfTills = 3;
        int numberOfFoodChoices = 4;
        Random rand = new Random();

        Tills[] tills = new Tills[numberOfTills];
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[numberOfWorkers];

        //int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff
        for (int i = 0; i < tills.length; i++) {
            int foodId = rand.nextInt(numberOfFoodChoices) + 1;
            tills[i] = new Tills(i, foodId, buff);
            tills[i].start();
        }

        //int workerId, Buffer buff
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Worker(i, buff);
            workers[i].start();
        }

        for (Tills till : tills) {
            try {
                till.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            try {
                worker.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
```

So as you can see by the main method I am looping and running the array of threads for both the worker and the tills.

Here is the tills class. So this creates the order. You will be able to see that I am using FastFood.semTills.down() and FastFood.semTills.up() this is using the semaphore. So down is acquiring the semaphore and up is releasing it. **However** the problem is my logic for the positioning of these semaphore downs and ups.

```
public class Tills extends Thread {
    private final Buffer buff;
    private final int foodId;
    private final int tillId;

    public Tills(int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff) {
        this.tillId = tillId;
        this.foodId = foodId;
        this.buff = buff;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        FastFood.semTills.down();
        while(FastFood.startOrders < FastFood.totalOrders){
            FastFood.semTills.up();
            buff.acquire(); 
            while(buff.isFull()){
                try {
                    buff.release();
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Tills.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            FastFood.startOrders++;
            Order v = new Order(foodId, tillId);
            System.out.println(v.toString());            
            try {
                Random n = new Random();
                int time = n.nextInt(100) + 1;
                buff.release();
                sleep(time);
                buff.insert(v);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }
    }
```

The worker class is somewhat the same, yet I want to ensure that only one worker can process a specific order at a time ( It is fine to enable multiple workers to enable multiple orders)

```
public class Worker extends Thread{
    private final int workerId;
    private final Buffer buff;


    public Worker(int workerId, Buffer buff) {
        this.workerId = workerId;
        this.buff = buff;
    }

    public void run(){
        FastFood.semWorker.down();
        while(FastFood.totalOrders>FastFood.processedOrders){
            buff.acquire();
            while(buff.isEmpty()){
                FastFood.semWorker.up();
                try {
                    buff.release();
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            FastFood.processedOrders++;
            System.out.print("Worker: " + workerId);
            buff.remove();
            buff.release();
            try {
                Random n = new Random();
                int time = n.nextInt(100) + 1;
                sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }
        FastFood.semWorker.up();
    }
```

This is the output I'm getting, you can see that it is not waiting for the orders to be processed, thus the positioning of my semaphores must be wrong, I've tried all sorts of possibilities:

```
run:
FoodId: 3 TillId : 1 Order Count : 0
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 1
FoodId: 4 TillId : 2 Order Count : 2
FoodId: 4 TillId : 2 Order Count : 3
FoodId: 4 TillId : 2 Order Count : 4
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 5
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 6
Worker: 1 Food: 3 TillId: 0
Worker: 0 Food: 3 TillId: 0
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 7
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 8
Worker: 1 Food: 3 TillId: 0
FoodId: 3 TillId : 0 Order Count : 9
FoodId: 3 TillId : 1 Order Count : 10
Worker: 0 Food: 3 TillId: 0
Worker: 1 Food: 3 TillId: 1
Worker: 0 Food: 3 TillId: 0
Worker: 1 Food: 4 TillId: 2
Worker: 0 Food: 3 TillId: 0
Worker: 1 Food: 4 TillId: 2
Worker: 0 Food: 3 TillId: 0
10
```

Quick Class Brief:

FastFood: Main, creates the threads
Buffer: For the circular array
Order: Stores what food from what till
Tills: Creates an order
Worker: Processes an order

Semaphore:

```
package fastfood;

public class Semaphore {

    private int count;

    public Semaphore(int n) {
        count = n;
    }

    public synchronized void down() {

        while (count == 0) {

            try {
                wait(); // Blocking call.
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        count--;
    }

    public synchronized void up() {
        count++;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Buffer:

```
public class Buffer {
    private int size;
    private int inPtr = 0;
    private int outPtr = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private Order[] data; 
    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    public Buffer(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.data = new Order[size];
    }

    public Order remove(){
        // removes the revote for the officer 
        Order out;
        out = data[outPtr];
        System.out.println(" Food: " + out.getFoodId() + " TillId: " + 
            out.getTillId());
        outPtr = (outPtr+1)%size;
        counter--;
        return out;
    }
    public void insert(Order i){
        // inserts a new vote 
        data[inPtr] = i;
        inPtr = (inPtr+1)%size;
        counter++;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        // returns true if empty
        return counter==0;
    }
    public boolean isFull(){
        // returns true if full
        return counter==size;
    }
    public void acquire(){
        sem.down();
    }
    public void release(){
        sem.up();
    }

}
```

CHANGES:

Change 2:

**Worker Class:**

```
public void run() {
       while(FastFood.processedOrders < FastFood.totalOrders){
           try{
                buff.acquire();
                FastFood.semWorker.down();
                while(buff.isEmpty()){
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                try{
                Order o = buff.remove();
                System.out.println(o.toString() + " FoodId: " + o.getFoodId() 
                        + " TillId: " + o.getTillId());
                FastFood.processedOrders++;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
           }finally{
               buff.release();
               FastFood.semTills.up();
           }

       }
```

Tills Class:

```
while (FastFood.startOrders < FastFood.totalOrders) {
            try {
                buff.acquire();
                FastFood.semTills.down();
                while (buff.isFull()) {
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Tills.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Order o = new Order(foodId, tillId);
                    System.out.println(o.toString());
                    buff.insert(o);
                    FastFood.startOrders++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            } finally {
                buff.release();
                FastFood.semWorker.up(); 
            }
```

Order:

```
public class Order {
    private final int foodId;
    private final int tillId;
    static int count = 0;
    private int orderCount=0;

    public Order(int foodId, int tillId){
        this.foodId = foodId;
        this.tillId = tillId;
        this.orderCount = count++;
    }

    public int getFoodId() {
        return foodId;
    }

    public int getTillId() {
        return tillId;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getOrderCount() {
        return orderCount;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FoodId: " +foodId+" TillId : "+tillId+" Order Count : "+ orderCount; 
    }
```

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` doesn't have any `up()` and `down()` methods, what kind of `Semaphore` are you using ?

Comment: My own, it does the same thing @Titus

Comment: @session_start *Your own?* How did you implement it? Where is the FastFood class by the way?

Comment: The main method @Elyasin it was the first code I posted

Comment: I think we'll need the code for both your semaphore and `Buffer`.  I don't understand the combination of `semTills.up()` and then `buff.acquire()`; it looks suspicious.

Comment: The buff.acquire is to allow access to enter or delete from the circular array, and the semaphore just prevents or allows access to the specific thread @markspace

Comment: But you do a `semTills.down()` and then a `semTills.up()` without accessing the buffer.   That can't be right.  You have to maintain mutex over the buffer the whole time you are actually using it.  The devil is in the details: code please.

Comment: My suspicion is that the OP developed his own `Semaphore` and `Buffer` classes and looking at the code I don't have a good feeling about that. We really need to see your code of these concurrent access mechanisms.

Comment: Check updates  @markspace

Comment: Check updates @Elyasin

Comment: Having had a quick look at your code, it's quite entangled, I'd recommend to use the `Semaphore` class from the Java library. Is there a reason not having done so? Also, in your code, the semaphore is manipulated by the `Buffer`, though `Till` and `Worker` manipulate the same. Do you mind if we dare to redesign your idea to make fit?

Comment: uhm, I want to try continue with the use of my semaphore.. there no way it could be done? @Elyasin

Comment: Well, not sure if it works properly. In the standard a semaphore has properties that yours does not provide: *fairness*, *list of waiting threads*, ... And I think *fairness* is maybe something you might consider when serving customer (in order)....

Comment: I'm just trying to make it random, not sure if fairness is an issue @Elyasin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are releasing your locks right after your while loop? Your tills are releasing them right after you check in your while loop. This seems very confusing. You want your till threads to sleep after their order is done and only awoken when their order is complete? And you want your workers to only specifically work on a certain order? Shouldn't the workers be able to work on any order as long as there are orders to waiting in your buffer? Sorry, I can't post in comments since I don't have 50 rep.

Fast Food

```
import java.util.*;

public class FastFood {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static Buffer buff = new Buffer(2);
static Semaphore semWorker = new Semaphore(2);
static Semaphore semTills = new Semaphore(2);
static int totalOrders = 10;
static int startOrders = 0;
static int processedOrders = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int numberOfWorkers = 2;
    int numberOfTills = 3;
    int numberOfFoodChoices =4;
    Random rand = new Random();

    Tills[] tills = new Tills[numberOfTills];
    Worker[] workers = new Worker[numberOfWorkers];

    //int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff
    for (int i = 0; i < tills.length; i++) {
        int foodId = rand.nextInt(numberOfFoodChoices) + 1;
        tills[i] = new Tills(i, foodId, buff);
        tills[i].start();
    }

    //int workerId, Buffer buff
    for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        workers[i] = new Worker(i, buff);
        workers[i].start();
    }

    for (Tills till : tills) {
        try {
            till.join();
        }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    for (Worker worker : workers) {
        try {
            worker.join();
        }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Buffer

```
public class Buffer {
private int size;
private int inPtr = 0;
private int outPtr = 0;
private int counter = 0;
private Order[] data; 


public Buffer(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.data = new Order[size];
}

public synchronized String remove(){
    // removes the revote for the officer 
    Order out;
    out = data[outPtr];
    outPtr = (outPtr+1)%size;
    counter--;
    return " Food: " + out.getFoodId() + " ordered by TillId: " + out.getTillId();
}
public synchronized void insert(Order i){
    // inserts a new vote 
    data[inPtr] = i;
    inPtr = (inPtr+1)%size;
    counter++;
}
public synchronized boolean isEmpty(){
    // returns true if empty
    return counter==0;
}
public synchronized boolean isFull(){
    // returns true if full
    return counter==size;
}


}
```

Tills

```
public class Tills extends Thread {
private final Buffer buff;
private final int foodId;
private final int tillId;

public Tills(int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff) {
    this.tillId = tillId;
    this.foodId = foodId;
    this.buff = buff;
}

public void run(){
    while(FastFood.startOrders < FastFood.totalOrders){
        FastFood.semTills.down();

        while(buff.isFull()){
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Tills.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        FastFood.startOrders++;
        Order v = new Order(foodId, tillId);
        buff.insert(v);
        System.out.println("Till number " + tillId + " created a new order " + foodId + " to be processed");
        FastFood.semWorker.up();

    }
}
}
```

Worker

```
public class Worker extends Thread{
private final int workerId;
private final Buffer buff;


public Worker(int workerId, Buffer buff) {
    this.workerId = workerId;
    this.buff = buff;
}

 public void run() {
    while (FastFood.totalOrders > FastFood.processedOrders) {
        FastFood.semWorker.down();
        while (buff.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        //FastFood.processedOrders++;
        System.out.println("Worker: " + workerId + " completed order number " + buff.remove() + " total orders processed so far: " + FastFood.processedOrders++);

        FastFood.semTills.up();
        try {
            Random n = new Random();
            int time = n.nextInt(100) + 1;
            sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Not sure if this is like your order class

```
public class Order{
private int tillID;
private int foodID;
public Order(int food, int till){
    tillID = till;
    foodID = food;
}

int getFoodId(){
    return foodID;
}

int getTillId(){
    return  tillID;
}

}
```

Before you try it out do note that it's not 100% correct. I got rid of the semaphore in the buffer and just made the methods synchronized. If you changed the semaphore values to 1 in the fastfood it would not run completely because not all the threads are able to wake back up to join at the end to exit the program.

Also, using static variables for totalOrders and processessOrders as a way to control when your threads stop running seem concerning because I think that threads each have their own copy so it might also lead to race conditions. I might be wrong though. I'm not sure what you haven't looked at yet but I think [this has some good information that might help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: Yeah you're right,  I want the tills to sleep until the order is done and I don't mind which worker does the job or what order.. That's what I'm getting at, I don't know where I should be putting the sleeps

Comment: Would it be better if you just let the Tills keep producing until they reach the order cap? That way they sleep only when there is no space to add an order and only wake them when there is space?  That way you could do something like while(true) -> check to see if your queue is full -> if full then sleep else -> produce.  Unless you really need to keep the till asleep until the order is produced then there wouldn't really be a point to have a total order amount since they would be capped by the tills.

Comment: Well keeping the till asleep when they make the order is kind of the reason why I'm doing this, obviously doing it without that would make it much easier @user2677821

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then. Why is there even a total order cap then? If the tills need to sleep right after they place an order everything might as well be sequential since there is nothing to keep one till and one worker potentially being the only ones active. I guess that is why the Semaphore is only 1. IF it really is the case you might as well make it so that after the till produces an order you make it sleep there and then in your worker after it finishes the order it wakes up the till. Because right now workers are waking workers and tills are waking up tills.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want to do @user2677821 I want the worker to notify the till to open it

Comment: Then change it? You want to grab the till semaphore in the while loop so that way when it loops again it sleeps since it wouldn't be able to grab it again since it would be 0 and you would do worker up at the end to wake up the worker.While in your worker class you would again grab the worker semaphore in the while loop and then at the end after you process the order you would then do the semaphore till up. Though only one till and one worker would ever work at anytime since you're semaphore values are only 1.

Comment: how would I make it so multiple can work at the same time? @user2677821

Comment: You would increase your semaphore count in your main. So like if you did Semaphore semTills = new Semaphore(2). But if you did it like that you could potentially have one till still doing all the work.

Comment: what about passing the semaphore as a parameter? so each time it creates a semaphore for that specific till? @user2677821

Comment: Why would you want one  semaphore per till? If you did that then each worker would need to know which semaphore to add back to.

Comment: Hey @user2677821 I've updated my question( is this how you mean do it?). I'm getting a null pointer exception now though

Comment: @user2677821 there, you have 50 rep. ;)

Comment: My guess is that one of your threads are trying to remove stuff when it's already empty. In your new worker run method you are doing FastFood.semWorker.up() right after checking if it's empty. Doing that is signaling other worker threads to wake up. Also in your Tills run method you are doing FastFood.semWorker.up() before you even insert the order. You should only wake them up after you have inserted the order. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm confused, can you show me what you mean in an edit to your answer? I got rid of the FastFood.semWorker.up() in the Worker class yet it doesn't seem to work, results are as follows.. run:
FoodId: 20 TillId : 0 Order Count : 0
Worker: 1FoodId: 32 TillId : 1 Order Count : 1
Worker: 2FoodId: 38 TillId : 2 Order Count : 2
Worker: 3FoodId: 37 TillId : 3 Order Count : 3
Worker: 2FoodId: 10 TillId : 4 Order Count : 4 @user2677821

Comment: I made even more changes, after watching 100 videos and reading 100 articles still can't get my code to give me the right output :( @user2677821 Check out my edit

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, The end value is adding a new order not removing.. also I've edited my question so you can view the Order class @user2677821

Comment: Also, is it not possible to do without the use of Synchronization? @user2677821

Comment: There is a value being added at the end because in one of the till threads, it wakes up after the 10th order is processed and it just adds an order without checking if the totalOrder has been reached yet. You probably could do without the synchronization if you want but it's probably going to lead to more problems.

Comment: How would I ensure that a thread won't wake up and add an order? @user2677821 Yeah well it was kind of the idea of the creation of my semaphore and buffer class, to try get it to work without the synchronizations and built in mutex's

Comment: You need to check if its not reached it's max. Also have you looked into vectors before, might be better than the buffer. You can use your own semaphore but if its built weird it's problematic. And I'm pretty sure yours would lead to race conditions. It's hard to debug because even if the code runs, it doesn't mean it's running correctly.

Comment: Yeah but how do I check its not reached its max with threads that have been sleeping? can you show me via the code? thank you @user2677821

Answer (score 1):

When `Worker` waits for order, it actually **waits for one of several events**:

1. `buffer` becomes non-empty.
2. All `Tills` finish their work, so no order will be generated ever.

It is better to combine all these events to single protection (`Semaphore` in your case). And move wait implementation into `Buffer` class:

```
public class Buffer {
    private int size;
    private int inPtr = 0;
    private int outPtr = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private Order[] data; 
    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    private bool isFinished; /* Whether no futher Orders will be added */
    public Buffer(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.data = new Order[size];
    }

    /* Put Order into buffer. If buffer is full, wait.*/
    public void put(Order i){
        sem.down();

        while(counter == size) // Buffer is full
        {
            // Some sort of busy wait
            sem.up();
            sleep(100);
            sem.down();
        }

        data[inPtr] = i;
        inPtr = (inPtr+1)%size;
        counter++;

        sem.up();
    }

    /* 
     *  Get order from the buffer and remove it.
     *  If buffer is empty and not finished, wait.
     *  Return null if buffer is empty and finished.
     */
    public Order get(){
        sem.down();

        while(counter == 0 && !isFinished)
        {
            // Some sort of busy wait
            sem.up();
            sleep(100);
            sem.down();
        }

        Order out;
        if(counter) // Otherwise `isFinished` is set and null should be returned.
        {
            out = data[outPtr];

            System.out.println(" Food: " + out.getFoodId() + " TillId: " + 
                out.getTillId());
            outPtr = (outPtr+1)%size;
            counter--;
        }

        sem.up();
        return out;
    }

    /* Mark buffer as finished. */
    void finish(void)
    {
        sem.down();
        isFinished = true;
        sem.up();
    }
}
```

Note, how busy waiting is performed: the semaphore is released, a thread sleeps some time and then the semaphore is acquired again.

Next, it is better to incorporate all logic about `officer` into separate class. It will be simple, but will consume `semTills` global semaphore:

```
class Officer
{
    private int totalOrders;
    private int startOrder;
    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    public Officer(int totalOrders) {
        this.totalOrders = totalOrders;
    }

    /* Return true if order is allowed, false otherwise. */
    public bool getOrder(void) {
        bool result;
        sem.down();
        if(startOrders != totalOrders) {
            startOrders++;
            result = true;
        }

        sem.up();
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, checking `startOrders` and modifying it should come under single critical section.

Next, `Tills` should wait, while *order*, produced by it, is processed. Such one-shot waiting can be implemented using initially locked `Semaphore`:

```
public class Tills extends Thread {
    private final Buffer buff;
    private final int foodId;
    private final int tillId;
    private final Semaphore waiter = Semaphore(0); // Initially locked!

    public Tills(int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff) {
        this.tillId = tillId;
        this.foodId = foodId;
        this.buff = buff;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(FastFood.officer.getOrder()){
            Order v = new Order(foodId, tillId);
            System.out.println(v.toString());            

            Random n = new Random();
            int time = n.nextInt(100) + 1;
            sleep(time);

            buff.put(v);

            //Wait order to be processed
            waiter.down();
        }
    }
    /* Tell that order, added to the buffer, is processed. */
    public markOrderProcessed(void) {
        waiter.up();
    }
}
```

Note, that implementation becomes much more simpler. Also class publishes method `markOrderProcessed` for being called by the `Worker`.

Because worker gets only *order* from the buffer, this object (of type `Order`) should contain reference to the `Tills`, created it. Also, `Order` objects can now be created concurrently. So its static `count` field should be protected by `Semaphore`.

```
public class Order {
    ...
    private Tills till; // New member
    static private Semaphore sem = Semaphore(1); // Protect *count* field

    public Order(..., Tills till) { // New parameter to the constructor
        ...
        this.till = till;

        // `count` should be incremented under protection.
        sem.down();
        this.orderCount = count++;
        sem.up();
    }

    /* New method: mark order as processed. */
    public markProcessed(void)
    {
        till.markOrderProcessed();
    }
}
```

Now everything is read for implement `Worker`'s *run* method. Note, that now this method doesn't use any sync directly, everything is done in low-level classes:

```
public void run(){
    Order order;
    while((order = buff.get()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Worker: " + workerId + " " + order);

        Random n = new Random();
        int time = n.nextInt(100) + 1;
        sleep(time);

        order.markProcessed(); // Mark order as processed, so tills can continue.
    }
}
```

And the main class. Note, that buffer is marked as finished only after all `Tills` are finished (joined):

```
public class FastFood {
    static Buffer buff = new Buffer(2);
    static Officer officer = new Officer(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int numberOfWorkers = 2;
        int numberOfTills = 3;
        int numberOfFoodChoices = 4;
        Random rand = new Random();

        Tills[] tills = new Tills[numberOfTills];
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[numberOfWorkers];

        //int tillId, int foodId, Buffer buff
        for (int i = 0; i < tills.length; i++) {
            int foodId = rand.nextInt(numberOfFoodChoices) + 1;
            tills[i] = new Tills(i, foodId, buff);
            tills[i].start();
        }

        //int workerId, Buffer buff
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Worker(i, buff);
            workers[i].start();
        }

        for (Tills till : tills) {
            try {
                till.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        /* 
         * Mark buffer as finished.
         * 
         * Workers, which found the buffer empty, may safetly stop now.
         */
        buff.finish();

        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            try {
                worker.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so confused with this syntax @Tsyvarev

Comment: Hmm, what a problem with my syntax? I tried to follow same conventions as the code in your question does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure half of its not java or am I being stupid? @Tsyvarev

Comment: This is just **your code** with *my modifications*. In `Order` class I show only my modifications, your code is under `...`.